# Apache Felix plus Jasper-JSP support - how to do it the proper way?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, osgi

In fact the question is: how to properly add tomcat-jasper jsp support to a felix osgi container?

I have managed to find a way to do it with minimal java custom code written, however I'm sure this is not the most 'clean' or 'proper' way to do it. There are still some limitations to this approach so this post is to show how I've done it and to ask how to do it 'properly'. Link to sample using eclipse: [sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b9vh20h85qrkdzs/jasper-osgi.zip?dl=0)

So what I've done is:

1. Set up Felix in the default http-whiteboard config plus webconsole support (not really required but... you can use it to check the jsp servlet deploys ok). I used the 5.4.0 dist as it seems to be the latest at this time.
2. Added 'jsp' and 'jstl' api specs, 'el' api spec + impl and 'ecj'  (already bundles in maven repo).
3. Bundelized the latest tomcat-jasper-8.0.32.jar (and dependencies) found in maven repos using `<Embed-Dependency>'inline'`, `<Import-Package>'*;resolution:=optional'` and `<DynamicImport-Package>'*'`. Yes, I know, big 'no-no', but one can't expect Jasper to know ahead what it will compile. Might be worth a shot without the DI-P. Later. Rebundelized same (but without DI-P) taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5 because though pom specifies xalan dependency optional, the bundle manifest does not. And decent/recent java has xml parsing built in,so I 'optionalized' it's dependencies as well. Anyway, I expect tomcat will osgi-fy it's jars one day and also produce a more osgi-friendly taglib-standard-impl.

Result is:

```
felix.base
  |-- bin
    |-- felix.jar
  |-- bundle
    |-- ecj-4.4.2.jar
    |-- javax.el-3.0.0.jar
    |-- javax.servlet.jsp-api-2.3.1.jar
    |-- javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar
    |-- org.apache.felix.bundlerepository-2.0.6.jar
    |-- org.apache.felix.configadmin-1.8.8.jar
    |-- org.apache.felix.eventadmin-1.4.6.jar
    |-- org.apache.felix.gogo.command-0.16.0.jar
    |-- org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime-0.16.2.jar
    |-- org.apache.felix.gogo.shell-0.10.0.jar
    |-- org.apache.felix.http.api-3.0.0.jar
    |-- org.apache.felix.http.base-3.0.6.jar
    |-- org.apache.felix.http.jetty-3.1.6.jar
    |-- org.apache.felix.http.servlet-api-1.1.2.jar
    |-- org.apache.felix.webconsole-4.2.14-all.jar
    |-- taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar
    |-- tomcat-api-8.0.32.jar
    |-- tomcat-jasper-8.0.32.jar
    |-- tomcat-jasper-el-8.0.32.jar
    |-- tomcat-juli-8.0.32.jar
    |-- tomcat-util-8.0.32.jar
    |-- tomcat-util-scan-8.0.32.jar
```

If you're looking at the attached sample then all described above is done by 'launcher/pom.xml'. Now if you start the 'launcher' (run as java application) all bundles should be active. So far no java coded, only 'customization' is the bundelization of tomcat jars and re-bundelization of taglib-standard-impl.

Now for the 'jsp-magic':

4. Created new bundle (used 'karaf-bundle' maven archetype). Activator and pom.xml for depends and bundle manifest below (taken from attached sample).

Activator:

```
public class Activator implements BundleActivator {
    public static String CONTEXT = "dummy";
    public static String BASE_URL = "/dummy";

    private ServletContextHelper servletContextHelper = null;
    private ServiceRegistration<?> schRegistration = null;
    private ServiceRegistration<Servlet> jspServletRegistration = null;

    public void start(BundleContext context) {
        // http support
        servletContextHelper = new ServletContextHelper() {
            @Override
            public URL getResource(String name) {
                if (name.startsWith("file:")) {
                    // this is an absolute URL, so it is already rendered
                    try {
                        return new URL(name);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                // render it in the webcontet dir
                return FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()).getResource("/webcontent" + name);
            }

            @Override
            public Set<String> getResourcePaths(String path) {
                if ("/WEB-INF/lib/".equals(path)) {
                    // jasper scans for tag libraries so give him all bundles in the container
                    Set<String> jars = new HashSet<String>();
                    Bundle thisBundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(ServletContextHelper.class);
                    try {
                        // look in the location of current bundle (assume they're all in the same place)
                        File deployDir = new File(new URI(thisBundle.getLocation())).getParentFile();
                        File[] files = deployDir.listFiles();
                        for (File file : files)
                            jars.add(file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return jars;
                }
                return super.getResourcePaths(path);
            }
        };

        Hashtable<String, Object> httpContextProps = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
        httpContextProps.put(HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_CONTEXT_NAME, CONTEXT);
        httpContextProps.put(HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_CONTEXT_PATH, BASE_URL);
        schRegistration = context.registerService(ServletContextHelper.class, servletContextHelper, httpContextProps);

        @SuppressWarnings("serial")
        JspServlet jspServlet = new JspServlet() {
            @Override
            public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
                JspFactory.setDefaultFactory(new JspFactoryImpl());

                ClassLoader current = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
                Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(JspServlet.class.getClassLoader());
                ServletContainerInitializer sci = new JasperInitializer();
                sci.onStartup(null, config.getServletContext());
                super.init(config);
                Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(current);
            }

            @Override
            public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
                ClassLoader current = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
                Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(JspServlet.class.getClassLoader());
                super.service(req, resp);
                Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(current);
            }

        };

        Hashtable<String, Object> jspProps = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
        jspProps.put(HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_SERVLET_NAME, "JSP servlet");
        jspProps.put(HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_SERVLET_PATTERN, "*.jsp");
        jspProps.put(HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_CONTEXT_SELECT, "(osgi.http.whiteboard.context.name=" + CONTEXT + ")");
        jspServletRegistration = context.registerService(Servlet.class, jspServlet, jspProps);
    }

    public void stop(BundleContext context) {
        jspServletRegistration.unregister();
        schRegistration.unregister();
    }
}
```

And bundle pom:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>dummy.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>dummy.jsp.osgi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <name>dummy.jsp.osgi</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <osgi.version>6.0.0</osgi.version>
        <osgi.http.whiteboard.version>1.0.0</osgi.http.whiteboard.version>
        <javax.servlet-api.version>3.1.0</javax.servlet-api.version>
        <javax.servlet.jsp-api.version>2.3.1</javax.servlet.jsp-api.version>
        <javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api.version>1.2.1</javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api.version>
        <javax.el-api.version>3.0.0</javax.el-api.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>${osgi.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.service.http.whiteboard</artifactId>
            <version>${osgi.http.whiteboard.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet-api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet.jsp-api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.32</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                        <Bundle-Activator>dummy.jsp.osgi.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                        <Export-Package>
                            dummy.jsp.osgi;version=${project.version},
                        </Export-Package>
                        <Import-Package>
                            *;resolution:=optional
                        </Import-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Open browser and go to localhost:8080/dummy/jsp/test.jsp and /testStandard.jsp. Both should render fine.

Translation of the above:

- the `JspServlet` needs to have the `JspFactory` set to `JspFactoryImpl`
  from the jasper jars, explicitly.
- the `JasperInitializer` must be called explicitly on startup as this is
  not the Tomcat servlet container but a 'bundelized' Jetty. Unless
  someone knows of a way to configure it somewhere somehow.
- the `JspServle`t needs to have the ClassLoader set to it's bundle's
  classloader on `init` and `service` calls
- the `ServletContextHelper` must resolve the `/WEB-INF/lib/` jars in
  order to provide taglib jars to jasper (the sample will render the 
  list of all deployed bundles)
- the `ServletContextHelper` must resolve corectly the invoked 'jsp'
  files to resources in the bundle(s)

The limitation I have found so far is that though `<jsp:include>` works but included `<jsp:param>`-s do not. Haven't figured out if it's related to my setup, jetty-related, felix-related or osgi-related. Any hint welcome in this respect.

Question is, how does one do this the RIGHT way? What config enhancements are there that can be done that will for example allow to skip the JasperInitializer call or the JspFactory explicit init. Haven't found much doc realting to this subject, mostly I've 'debugged' tomcat and felix.

Comment: oops no sample attached and can't see how. can provide on demand.

Comment: fixed sample availability in [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b9vh20h85qrkdzs/jasper-osgi.zip?dl=0)